# Javafx: Automatic update of table cell using Thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I have a `Trade` class which contains a property `currentPrice`, which downloads price data from a website using `getPricedata()` method. The `Trade` object will show up as a table row in `TableView`. Now, **my task:** is to

- use the `getPricedata()` method to grab data from internet, populate the `currentPrice` cell, whenever the object is created.
- relaunch the `getPricedata()` method to every 1 minute after the object has been created and update table cell.

Below is the basic structure of my code. But I have no idea how to implement this ? 
Which package do I need ? `Task` ? `Service` ? `ScheduledService` ?

```
public class Trade{

     private DoubleProperty currentPrice;

     // need thread here
     public double getPricedata(){
             .......
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ScheduledService<Number>`, whose `Task<Number>`'s `call()` method retrieves and returns the value. Then you can either register an `onSucceeded` handler with the service, or just bind the `Trade`'s `currentPrice` to `service.lastValue()`. Call `setPeriod(..)` on the service (once) to configure it to run every minute.

Since the `currentPrice` is being set from the service, you should only expose a `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty` from your `Trade` class (otherwise you might try to call `currentPriceProperty().set(...)` or `setCurrentPrice(...)`, which would fail as it's bound).

I would do something like

```
public class Trade {

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper currentPrice ;

    private final ScheduledService<Number> priceService = new ScheduledService<Number>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Number> createTask() {
            return new Task<Number>() {
                @Override
                public Number call() {
                    return getPriceData();
                }
            };
        }
    };

    public Trade() {
        priceService.setPeriod(Duration.minutes(1));

        // in case of errors running service:
        priceService.setOnFailed(e -> priceService.getException().printStackTrace());

        currentPrice = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(0);
        currentPrice.bind(priceService.lastValueProperty());
        startMonitoring();
    }

    public final void startMonitoring() {
        priceService.restart();
    }

    public final void stopMonitoring() {
        priceService.cancel();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty currentPriceProperty() {
       return currentPrice.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final double getCurrentPrice() {
        return currentPriceProperty().get();
    }

    private double getPriceData() {
        // do actual retrieval work here...
    }
}
```

(Code just typed in here without testing, but it should give you the idea.)

Comment: HI @James_D, do you mind giving me an example code? It's a bit hard for me to follow. Thanks! And is using `DoubleProperty` a good choice ?

Comment: See update (code untested, both at the compile and at the run level).

Comment: I got a exception error message , when I do `testTrade.getCurrentPrice()`.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized`

Comment: That's pretty much different; it sounds like you are trying to run this outside of a JavaFX application.

Comment: Sorry about that. I shouldn't be running it outside the JavaFX application. I created a separate class to check that my `getPriceData()` is working correctly and it managed to get the correct data and I printed it out on the console. However, when I bind this into my JavaFX application. The column only shows 0 for the current price. I do not understand why this is happening. Nonetheless, I am sure my `getPriceData()` code is running fine.

Comment: Register a `setOnFailed` handler with the service and log any exceptions.

Comment: How would I do that ? Can you show me please ? Thanks!

Comment: So debug it. What is on line 192?

Comment: I am so sorry. It was a careless mistake again. I was way too exhausted after. Wasn't thinking straight after work.